# One to many intersection of polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection

using QGIS 2.18.16 I am trying to figure out how to find out what polygons  in layer one (blue) intersects the polygons in layer 2 (red\pink).  I know that there will be more than one intersection for most of the polygons in layer 1 (blue) but not sure how to calc it. In a perfect world I would like to add it as a attribute to the polygon in layer 1.

[image]

Comment: what data system are you using?

Comment: Data System?  I am using QGIS 2.18 and shape flies

Comment: I have used the intersection  function under Vector> Geoprocessing Tools .  This gives me the data but not in one to many way i am looking for it. it is many to one.  Any help would be great.

Comment: I would prefer to do this in a relational databases where many-to-one relationships are better handled, especially for geometry... you may be able to use the DB manager in QGIS to write a SQL spatial query against your shapefiles to join the features - if that might work for you, I'll see if I can write a sample...

Comment: DISCLAIMER: not a QGIS guy, but GIS is GIS, right?  When you use the Intersection Function under Vector>Geoprocessing Tools, switch the source and target parameters so you are intersecting red 1/16 section polys with blue plat maps ... I mean reverse the two arguments of the function.  Think B on A, not A on B.  -- This isn't an "Answer" to your problem but rather assistance with the concept behind the QGIS function.

Comment: @lowsparked so did you get that to work? all answers here are working perfectly...would be great if any form of acknowledgement would come from your end ,)

Answer (score 4):

I found the following to work well on my small sample, though it involves repeated iteration through the layer1 features, so it might be slow on a large dataset. Also, I used QGIS 3.0.0. I am not sure how much it differs from 2.18.16.

First, load data (pardon my crooked quarter sections):

[image: quarter sections and layer 1]

Second, use "Vector > Data Management Tools > Join Attributes By Location" to join the two layers. I selected "contains" in addition to "intersects" under *geometric predicates* to cover cases like polygon 2, where it doesn't cross the border of a quarter section. Use layer 1 (blue) as the input and the quarter sections as the join layer. Use the *create separate feature for each located feature* option under "join type".

[image: settings for join by location]

This will create duplicate polygons wherever a layer1 polygon intersects with more than quarter section.

[image: duplicated polygons]

Lastly, we use the new joined layer to write the correct quarter section names into the original layer1 file with a bit of python.

```
# add layers and add new attribute to layer1
joined = QgsVectorLayer("...some path/joined.shp", "Joined layer", "ogr")
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer("...some path/layer1.shp", "layer1", "ogr")
res = layer1.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("QS_list", QVariant.String)])
joined.updateFields()
layer1.updateFields()

# iterate through the layer1 features and for each,
# iterate through the joined features and for each,
# if the layer1 and joined IDs match, add the QS name to a list
# finally sort the list and write it into the new layer1 attribute
for feature in layer1.getFeatures():
    ID = feature.id()
    QS_list = []
    for feature_joined in joined.getFeatures():
        attrs = feature.attributes()
        attrs_joined = feature_joined.attributes()
        if attrs_joined[0] == attrs[0]:
            QS_list.append(str(attrs_joined[1]))
    layer1.startEditing()
    layer1.changeAttributeValue(ID, 1, str(sorted(QS_list)))
    layer1.updateFields()
    layer1.commitChanges()
```

[image: results after python code]

There appears to be a trick to doing this in ArcGIS also (and it looks way easier). [Spatial Join’s hidden trick or how to transfer attribute values in a One to Many relationship](https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/spatial-joins-hidden-trick-or-how-to-transfer-attribute-values-in-a-one-to-many-relationship/)

Here are the steps (the post on Esri Australia Technical Blog also has screen captures). I didn't test this.

> In the Spatial Join tool’s dialog navigate to the Zoning field in the dataset that is being joined and Right-click on it. Choose Properties.
>
> Set the following:
>
> Length: set the value which will be capable of storing the appropriate number of characters
>
> Merge Rule: use Join
>
> Delimiter: use any delimiter you like
>
> Set the cardinality in the Spatial Join tool to “One to One”
>   Run the tool.
>   The resulting dataset should display zones that each of the property boundary polygons intersect, stored as text values separated by the delimiter of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not familiar with or just not willing to use SQL in any way, you can also simply use the *Field Calculator* (the summary aggregate functions should be available from QGIS 2.16.x on):

- *layer1* | `Open Field Calculator` | *`New Field`*

  - *`Output field type`* = *`Text (string)`*
- type in *`Expression`*:

  ```
  aggregate(layer:=<layer>, aggregate:='concatenate', concatenator:=',', expression:="<field>", filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
  ```

  - select `layer2` name as `<layer>` under *`Map layers`*
  - replace `<field>` with fieldname of interest in `layer2` (double quotes have to stay!)
  - if `<field>` is not of type `string`, use `expression:=to_string("<field>")`
- `OK` should add the above field to the attribute table of `layer1` as a concatenated string
- save/quit edit mode (has been auto enabled)

Comment: join attributes by location and then this calculation was magic. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I´d go for a *Virtual Layer* using the natively supported *SQLite/SpatiaLite* SQL dialect:

- *`Layer`* | *`Add Layer`* | *`Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`*
- *`Embedded Layers`* | *`Add`* (from file) / *`Import`* (from project) | *select both polygon layers*
- Assuming their names are `layer1` and `layer2` with an `id` column
  each and an attribute `val` in `layer2` that you are interested in, running

  ```
  SELECT a.*,
         GROUP_CONCAT(b.val) AS vals
  FROM layer1 AS a
  JOIN layer2 AS b
    ON ST_Intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
  GROUP BY a.id
  ```

  in it´s *`Query`* field will copy all attributes/geometries from
  `layer1` plus a concatenated string field `vals`, with the `val`'s
  from `layer2` that intersect each polygon in `layer1`, into the
  *Virtual Layer*.
- Click *`Add`* and save to file (e.g. *layer context* | *`Save as...`*)

---

The more versatile way would be to use the *DB Manager* (as @DPSSpatial also mentioned in his comment I only just read...); this is a full scale DB client, capable of also runnning queries against the project layers (you'll find all currently loaded layers under *`Virtual Layers`* | *`QGIS Layers`* on the left) using the *SQLite/SpatiaLite* SQL dialect;

- E.g. when executing the same query, you will be presented a result table
  including a *geometry* field to check against.
- Tick *`Load as new layer`* and save the created layer to file (don´t
  forget to specify a geometry column if not already set).