# QGIS Tool/Script to run that highlights location point features within their respective polygon feature based on the same parcel ID

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select-by-location

**Software**: QGIS Desktop 3.0.3

**Data Type**: Vector Point and Polygon
   feature layers

**Action**: Select based on particular field matching and
   return/highlight based on geographic location according to a
   particular rule (point feature lies within polygon feature)

I have a large data-set (80,000+) of point features for homes in the state of Florida. The point feature layer has a field showing the parcel #.

I also have a polygon layer highlighting parcel boundaries for the parcels in the state of Florida with a field that also shows parcel #.

I am trying to create/discover a tool or script to run that will a take that a sample set (10,000) of points I've manually extracted from the point feature layer, and select/highlight/return all point features that fall within the boundary of the specific polygon parcel boundary layer feature that matches the same parcel # number as the point feature. So in a nutshell,

I want to:

- Match up the point features and polygon features that have matching(identical) Parcel Numbers in their attributes
- Select/return all points that do or do not lie entirely within their respective polygon feature with the same parcel number as the point feature
- This will provide me with a quick way of QA/QC that most (95%) of the point features are in their correct geographic (lat/long) location.

Comment: I do not at all see this question as off-topic. Your hardness will have newcomers end up having a difficult time asking a question.  This problem could also be solved without code using existing dialogs of QGIS, leaving the specific reason for put on hold obsolete. Give the man a chance :)

Comment: >>Dan C, Vince, PolyGeo: Here is another one you can but on hold; No code but a solution available using SQL: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284670/one-to-many-intersection-of-polygons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use Virtual Layers - the hidden force of QGIS**

I can not come up with an easier answer than using Virtual Layers. You can use two Virtual Layers in QGIS joining the tabels on your needs.

Having two test tables mypoint and mypolygon:

[image]

**Find all points matching polygon layer parcelid and within polygon:**

```
select poi.geometry, poi.parcelid, poly.parcelid 
from mypoint poi
inner join mypolygon poly using (parcelid)
where st_within(poi.geometry, poly.geometry)
```

Showing as the blue points:

[image]

**Find all points matching a polygon layer parcelid but not within polygon with matching parcelid**

```
select poi.geometry, poi.parcelid, poly.parcelid 
from mypoint poi
inner join mypolygon poly using (parcelid)
where not st_within(poi.geometry, poly.geometry)
```

Showing as the red points:

[image]

**You can find the Virtual Layers editor within the Datasource Manager**

[image]

Note Virtual Layers are dynamic. Changing the point and polygons will automatically update the Virtual Layers on a map refresh.

Comment: Jakob, This method definitely worked. Just cut my QA/QC time down to a matter of minutes. Appreciate it dude!